# Parsing a huge file in Fortran

Tags: parsing, fortran

I am trying to parse an output file of a popular QM program, in order to extract data corresponding to two related properties: 'frequencies' and 'intensities'. An example of how the output file looks can be found below:

```
 Max difference between off-diagonal Polar Derivs IMax=       2 JMax=       3 KMax=      13 EMax= 8.65D-04
 Full mass-weighted force constant matrix:
 Low frequencies ---   -2.0296   -1.7337   -1.3848   -0.0005   -0.0003    0.0007
 Low frequencies ---  216.4611  263.3990  368.1703
 Diagonal vibrational polarizability:
       18.1080784       9.1046025      11.9153848
 Diagonal vibrational hyperpolarizability:
      127.1032599       2.7794305      -8.7599786
 Harmonic frequencies (cm**-1), IR intensities (KM/Mole), Raman scattering
 activities (A**4/AMU), depolarization ratios for plane and unpolarized
 incident light, reduced masses (AMU), force constants (mDyne/A),
 and normal coordinates:
                     1                      2                      3
                     A                      A                      A
 Frequencies --   216.4611               263.3989               368.1703
 Red. masses --     3.3756                 1.0427                 3.0817
 Frc consts  --     0.0932                 0.0426                 0.2461
 IR Inten    --     3.6192                21.7801                 0.2120
 Raman Activ --     1.0049                 0.1635                 0.9226
 Depolar (P) --     0.6948                 0.6536                 0.7460
 Depolar (U) --     0.8199                 0.7905                 0.8546
  Atom  AN      X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z
     1   6     0.00   0.00   0.22     0.00   0.01   0.02     0.06   0.15  -0.01
     2   7     0.00   0.00   0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00     0.10  -0.02   0.00
     3   6     0.00   0.00  -0.23     0.00  -0.01   0.00     0.01  -0.07   0.00
     4   6     0.00   0.00   0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    -0.08  -0.02   0.00
     5   6     0.00   0.00   0.21     0.00   0.01  -0.03    -0.06   0.15   0.00
     6   6     0.00   0.00   0.11     0.00   0.01   0.00    -0.01   0.17   0.00
     7   7    -0.02   0.00  -0.22     0.00   0.03   0.00    -0.01  -0.26   0.00
     8   1     0.10  -0.02  -0.32     0.02  -0.30   0.66     0.34  -0.39  -0.13
     9   1     0.07  -0.02  -0.39    -0.05  -0.25  -0.63    -0.37  -0.40   0.12
    10   1     0.00   0.00   0.39     0.01   0.01   0.07     0.18   0.22  -0.03
    11   1     0.00   0.00  -0.53     0.00  -0.01   0.01     0.02  -0.15   0.01
    12   1     0.00   0.00  -0.03    -0.01   0.00  -0.02    -0.18  -0.09   0.00
    13   1     0.00   0.00   0.31     0.00   0.00  -0.09    -0.18   0.22   0.03
                     4                      5                      6
                     A                      A                      A
 Frequencies --   411.0849               501.4206               548.5728
 Red. masses --     3.4204                 2.8766                 6.5195
 Frc consts  --     0.3406                 0.4261                 1.1559
 IR Inten    --     4.2311                30.8234                 6.3698
 Raman Activ --     0.1512                 0.8402                 4.2329
 Depolar (P) --     0.7404                 0.1511                 0.4224
 Depolar (U) --     0.8508                 0.2625                 0.5939
  Atom  AN      X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z
     1   6     0.00   0.00   0.20     0.00  -0.01   0.01     0.02  -0.12  -0.01
     2   7     0.00   0.00  -0.21     0.00   0.00  -0.16     0.06  -0.18   0.02
     3   6     0.00   0.00  -0.03     0.01   0.00   0.15     0.32  -0.01  -0.02
     4   6     0.00   0.00   0.27     0.01   0.00  -0.08     0.18   0.10   0.01
     5   6     0.00   0.00  -0.23     0.00   0.00  -0.03     0.11   0.19   0.00
     6   6     0.00   0.00  -0.02     0.00   0.00   0.32    -0.26   0.01  -0.04
     7   7     0.00  -0.01   0.01    -0.04   0.00  -0.04    -0.39   0.02   0.04
     8   1    -0.01   0.05  -0.10     0.17   0.03  -0.36    -0.36   0.06  -0.08
     9   1    -0.02   0.04   0.16     0.15  -0.01  -0.35    -0.30   0.02  -0.11
    10   1     0.01   0.01   0.48     0.01   0.00  -0.35     0.22  -0.01   0.03
    11   1     0.00   0.00  -0.12     0.01   0.00   0.23     0.31   0.13  -0.02
    12   1     0.00   0.00   0.54     0.00   0.00  -0.39    -0.02  -0.03   0.05
    13   1    -0.01   0.00  -0.47     0.01   0.00  -0.45     0.34   0.06   0.04
                     7                      8                      9
                     A                      A                      A
 Frequencies --   629.8582               652.6212               716.4846
 Red. masses --     7.0000                 1.4491                 2.4272
 Frc consts  --     1.6362                 0.3637                 0.7341
 IR Inten    --     9.4587               253.3389                18.8342
 Raman Activ --     3.5151                11.7363                 0.2311
 Depolar (P) --     0.7397                 0.2892                 0.7423
 Depolar (U) --     0.8504                 0.4486                 0.8521
  Atom  AN      X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z
     1   6     0.24  -0.18  -0.01    -0.02   0.03  -0.04     0.00   0.00  -0.12
     2   7     0.30   0.27   0.02    -0.02   0.00   0.04     0.00   0.00   0.17
     3   6     0.06   0.12  -0.02    -0.03  -0.01  -0.04     0.00   0.00  -0.15
     4   6    -0.23   0.23   0.01     0.02  -0.04   0.02     0.00   0.00   0.18
     5   6    -0.22  -0.20  -0.01     0.02   0.00  -0.04     0.00   0.00  -0.08
     6   6    -0.04  -0.15  -0.02     0.04   0.01  -0.04     0.00   0.00   0.13
     7   7    -0.13  -0.07   0.06    -0.05   0.00   0.14     0.01   0.00  -0.01
     8   1     0.02  -0.03  -0.20     0.30   0.13  -0.57     0.00  -0.02   0.05
     9   1     0.00  -0.12  -0.26     0.29  -0.10  -0.63    -0.01   0.02   0.05
```

the code I'm using is:

```
     program gau_parser
     implicit none
     integer :: ierr    ! Error value for read statement
     integer, parameter :: iu = 20 ! input unit
     integer, parameter :: ou = 30 ! output unit
     character (len=*), parameter :: search_str = " Frequencies --"  ! this is the property I'm looking for
     !                                            ^===============^   there are 15 characters here. First character is blank.
     !
     ! NOTE: a typical string looks like this: " Frequencies --   411.0849               501.4206               548.5728"
     !                                           ==============   ========               ========               ========
     !                                             search_str       xx(1)                  xx(2)                  xx(3)
     !
     ! the string length is 73 but may be variable but very seldomly more than 80
     !
     real :: xx(3)                       ! this will be the three values associated to the above property
     character (len=80) :: text
     character (len=15) :: word

    open (unit=iu,file="dummy.log",action="read")   ! read the file I wish to parse
    open (unit=ou,file='output.log',action="write") ! Open a file where I wish the parse results to be written to!

    do                                  ! the search is done line by line, until the end of the file
     read (iu,"(a)",iostat=ierr) text   ! read line into character variable
        
        if (ierr /= 0) then
        cycle                           ! If a reading error occurs, advance to new line
        end if                       
             
    read (text,*) word                  ! read first word of line
    
      if (word == search_str) then      ! found search string at beginning of line
      read (text,*) word,xx             ! read the entire line
      write(30,*) word,xx               ! write the entire line
    end if
    
    end do                              ! finish the search cycle
    end program gau_parser
```

My questions are following:

a) The present code is compilable, but 'hangs up' upon execution. Can anyone compile their own version and see if the same is happening to them? What (user induced) error may be causing such behavior?

b) How can I make the multiple values of 'xx' be written in a single array in sequence? That is, they should be read like this from the parsed file

```
word xx(1) xx(2) xx(3)
...
junk
...
word xx(4) xx(5) xx(6)
... 
more junk
...
word xx(7) xx(8) xx(9)
```

I know that I've stated in the program the array to be of dimension(3), but that is just for test sake. In reality, it must be allocated but unspecified until, upon reaching the end of the parsed file, it must  `INQUIRE:SIZE`. My idea is to print it into a scratch file, evaluate it, and the write it back in memory, as `xx(INQUIRE:SIZE)` dimension array. Any thought on the matter would be most welcome!

---

**EDIT**: After trying to debug the program, I realized that it was actually looping! I've inserted a couple of `write` statements to see what could be going wrong

```
 open (unit=iu,file="dummy.log",action="read")   ! read the file I wish to parse
        print*,'file opened'
      !  open (unit=ou,file='output.log',action="write") ! Open a file where I wish the parse results to be written to!
        do                                  ! the search is done line by line, until the end of the file
         print*,'Do loop has started'
         read (iu,"(a)",iostat=ierr) text   ! read line into character variable
            
            if (ierr /= 0) then
            write(*,*)'Error!'
            cycle                           ! If a reading error occurs, advance to new line
            end if
```

and ... voilà! My screen started to be filled up by a flurry of

```
 Error!
 Do has started
```

messages! In essence, I'm stuck in a loop! Where have I failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle error in the code.  The statement

```
read (iu,"(a)",iostat=ierr) text   ! read line into character variable
```

reads a line of text from the file into the variable `text`, and it uses the edit descriptor `"(a)"` which means that `text` is what you expect it to be.  On the other hand the statement

```
read (text,*) word
```

uses *list directed* input (that's what the `*` means) and it does not get, for example, the string  `Frequencies` from the line.  Helpfully the compiler strips off the leading blank characters and `word` gets the string `Frequencies` (no leading space).  This will never match the searched-for string.

> An aside: especially when developing codes do not let loops run
> indefinitely, put in a reasonable maximum loop iteration, eg `do ix = 1,200` for your test case, this will stop you wasting time staring at
> a computation which ain't ever going to finish.

The reason that the code runs forever is that there is no end condition.  Instead, the block of code

```
if (ierr /= 0) then
cycle                           ! If a reading error occurs, advance to new line
end if
```

sends execution back to the `do` statement - *ad infinitum*.  I would use a stopping condition like this:

```
IF (IS_IOSTAT_END(ierr)) EXIT
```

The function `IS_IOSTAT_END` frees you from having to figure out what error code end-of-file causes on your compiler, the values of those codes are not standardised.  `IS_IOSTAT_EOR` is useful to check for end-of-record.

The next error you will find is that the statement

```
read (text,*) word
```

won't make `word` match `Frequencies --` either.  Again, using *list-directed* input means that the compiler will treat blank spaces in the input file as separators, and the line of code will only get `Frequencies` into `word`.  But that leads to another problem,

```
read (text,*) word,xx             ! read the entire line
```

will try to read the string `--` into the real variable `xx`, with unhappy results.

One, perhaps the, solution to this series of problems, is to use an explicit edit descriptor in the read statements, like this.  First change

```
read (text,*) word
```

to

```
read (text,'(a15)') word
```

Next, you have to change the line to read `xx` to *something like*

```
read (text,'(a15,3(f18.4))') word,xx             ! read the entire line
```

You will find that, as it stands, this line does not read all 3 values into `xx` correctly.  That's because the edit descriptor `3(f18.4)` does not quite properly describe the layout of the line, in fact it may need `f(18.4),2(fNN.4)`, where of course you replace `NN` by the proper field width for your file.  And it's time you did some of the work.